# Regexp exactly seven digits

Tags: .net, regex

How can I write regular expression which meets the requirements:
7 digits that come one after another in a row

Comment: Please update your question with what you have tried

Comment: http://www.regular-expressions.info/ is a good place to start learning regular expressions.

Comment: show an example input.

Comment: @Alex: And what is the problem with it? That should work.

Comment: are there spaces between your digits?

Answer (score 3):

`/^\d{7}$/` should do the trick.

Please consider looking by yourself, this is pretty trivial.

Answer (score 2):

Like this: `\d{7}` or `[0-9]{7}` or `[:digit:]{7}` or explicitly like `\d\d\d\d\d\d\d` or `[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]` depends of the language/tool you are using. Those will all match a string of 7 digits but you will need to anchor the match so only exactly 7 digits are matched using the start and end characters like `^\d{7}$` or some type of boundary like whitespace `\s\d{7}\s`.

Note: `{n}` is part of the extended regexp class.

Comment: I use .net. Interesting but this \d{7} not working with string 11202994 202074 INV 06 12 12 1418

Comment: It's Regex.IsMatch returns true. Why?

Comment: To get better answers you should have tagged the question `.net` posted your code.