# blocking seven digit numbers in string pandas

Tags: regex, python-3.x, pandas, text, replace

**Background**

I have the following sample df

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'Text':['This person num is 111-888-8888 and other',
                          'dont block 23 here',
                          'two numbers: 001-002-1234 and some other 123-123-1234 here',
                          'block this 666-666-6666',
                           '1-510-999-9999 is one more'], 
                  'P_ID': [1,2,3,4,5],
                  'N_ID' : ['A1', 'A2', 'A3','A4', 'A5']}) 

    N_ID    P_ID    Text
0   A1  1   This person num is 111-888-8888 and other
1   A2  2   dont block 23 here
2   A3  3   two numbers: 001-002-1234 and some other 123-1...
3   A4  4   block this 666-666-6666
4   A5  5   1-510-999-9999 is one more
```

**Goal**

1) Block all seven digit numbers e.g. `111-888-8888` becomes `**Block**`

2) Avoid blocking non-seven digit numbers e.g. `23`

3) Create new column

**Tried**

I have tried the following

```
df['New_Text'] = df['Text'].str.replace(r'\d+','**Block**')
```

But it blocks all numbers

**Also Tried**

I have also tried changing the `\d+` with many other version e.g. `/^\d{7}$/` taken from  [Regexp exactly seven digits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14773364/regexp-exactly-seven-digits) and e.g `^[0-9]{7}` taken from 
[Regex to match "<seven digits> - <filename>" with only one set of seven digits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47833208/regex-to-match-seven-digits-filename-with-only-one-set-of-seven-digits) and e.g `\b[0-9]{7}(?![0-9])` taken from
[REGEX To get seven numbers in a row?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18261443/regex-to-get-seven-numbers-in-a-row) but they all don't work.

**Desired Output**

```
    N_ID P_ID Text  New_Text
0                   This person num is **Block** and other
1                   dont block 23 here
2                   two numbers: **Block**  and some other **Block** 
3                   block this **Block** 
4                   1-**Block**  is one more
```

**Question**

How do I tweak my code to achieve my desired output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this regex expression. `((?:[\d]-?){7,})`

[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/XappiS/2)

Final block of code is this

```
df['New_Text'] = df['Text'].str.replace(r'((?:[\d]-?){7,})','**Block**')
```