# modification of blocking seven digit numbers in string pandas

Tags: python, regex, pandas, text, replace

**Background**

I have the following df which is a modification from [blocking seven digit numbers in string pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57385758/blocking-seven-digit-numbers-in-string-pandas)

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'Text':['This person num is (111)888-8780 and other',
                          'dont block 23 here',
                          'two numbers: 001-002-1234 and here',
                          'block this (666)6636666',
                           '1-510-999-9999 is one more'], 
                  'P_ID': [1,2,3,4,5],
                  'N_ID' : ['A1', 'A2', 'A3','A4', 'A5']}) 


N_ID    P_ID    Text
0   A1  1   This person num is (111)888-8780 and other
1   A2  2   dont block 23 here
2   A3  3   two numbers: 001-002-1234 and here
3   A4  4   block this (666)6636666
4   A5  5   1-510-999-9999 is one more
```

**Goal**

1) Block all seven digit numbers with parenthesis e.g. `(111)888-8780` and `(666)6636666` become `**Block**`

2) Avoid blocking non-seven digit numbers e.g. `23`

3) Create new column

**Tried**

```
df['New'] = df['Text'].str.replace(r'((?:[\d]-?){7,})','**block**')
```

**Output**

```
    N_ID P_ID Text New
0                  This person num is (111)**block** and other
1                  dont block 23 here
2                  two numbers: **block** and here
3                  block this (666)**block**
4                   **block** is one more
```

but this fails to fully block `(111)888-8780` and `(666)6636666`

**Question**

How do I tweak `str.replace(r'((?:[\d]-?){7,})` to fully block numbers in parenthesis e.g. `(111)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possibility is to include the set of all characters that you would like to remove in a character class.

```
df['New'] = df['Text'].str.replace(r'[()\d-]{7,}','**block**')
```

Here, the set of characters includes parentheses, digits and the hyphen. These must occur at least seven times. This returns

```
df['New']
Out[14]: 
0    This person num is **block** and other
1                        dont block 23 here
2           two numbers: **block** and here
3                      block this **block**
4                     **block** is one more
Name: New, dtype: object
```